# How do I get Time Lapse View in P4Win?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v, p4win

In the past, on Windows XP machines, I was able to install P4V (the stupid platform-independent Perforce visual client that Perforce tries to shove down your throats), then after that, install P4Win (the wonderful clean robust mature visual client that Perforce is stupidly trying to deprecate).

If I did the installs in that order (and only in that order), I would get an option for "time lapse view" of a file when I right-clicked on it in a Perforce depot in P4Win. This would launch the time lapse view app that came with P4V, and everyone would be happy.

I just did those steps in Vista and... no dice. I don't see the Time Lapse View option when I right-click on a file.

Anyone know what wonky sequence of install steps I need to do under Vista to get this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I did this myself. The steps I followed were:
1. Uninstall every single Perforce product on my machine.
2. Reboot.
3. Install P4V.
4. Reboot.
5. Insteall P4Win.
6. Reboot.

Then the Time-Lapse View (and the Revision Graph, another useful tool you can only get from the P4V tools) show up in P4Win. Huzzah!

By the way I tried uninstalling them all, then reinstalling in the right order WITHOUT any of those reboot steps... no dice. Probably not all of those reboot steps are necessary, but I wanted to be sure, and it worked.

I'd like to take this space to say once more: P4V is donkey feces, and Perforce needs to stop trying to shove it down our throats and continue to build on the fantastic product they have in P4Win. kthxbye.

Comment: I disagree with the P4V opinion. Once you get your head around it you will find it generally better and easier to do 90% of your tasks. There's a few things it falls down on compared to P4Win, but these are getting sorted over time. BTW, 2008.2 has just been released - I recommend you give p4V a go.

Comment: What Greg said.  The P4V client does lack some P4Win features.  However, P4Win now lacks loooooads of features offered by P4V, from simple things like simple file moves with automatic re-open for edit through to large features like shelving.  I don't like the feel of the P4V GUI (does my head in when it resizes the window when switching sub-panes), but in general I prefer it over P4Win nowadays.  A lot of my colleagues had the same opinion and preferred P4Win, but most of them have now made the jump to P4V.

Answer (score 1):

This method also works for Windows 7 64 bit with 64 bit versions of P4V and P4Win